# Xcode Bots won't show up in Xcode / "Error Reading Settings" in Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, server, xcode-server

Sometimes i have problems with my Xcode server running on a separate mac mini. On my Macbook the Xcode bots won't show up and/or I can't connect to the Xcode server in the settings pane.

My Xcode server running on a mac mini also shows me "Error Reading Settings" error sometimes...

[image]

I also reset Xcode server already but after a while it doesn't work again.

**UPDATE**

Currently it's working again since a couple days. What my changes were:

I was having only the "xcodeserver" user on the server machine. I added my personal account and I changed it to have the xcodeserver user running the service and the tests and my personal user to run the Server App. I'm really not sure what it changed under the hood, but it works for now.

Comment: I feel with you. We have the same problem. We setup a new build server from scratch, and even though there are no bots configured yet, it shows this error on the new machine... Did you find a solution meanwhile?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. So you also reinstalled macOS again?

Comment: Yes. Actually it is a second mac mini, setup from scratch with nothing on it yet but a fresh server and xcode installation.

Comment: Ok i also erased the whole partition and created it again. it works for now. but when i did it the first time it worked in the beginning too. it stopped after a couple months. i also tried to setup a webserver on the same machine a while ago. maybe something went wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed few seconds ago.

1. Backup /Library/Server/named
2. Remove files from /Library/Server/named
3. Reinstall Server app
4. Look into saved files and reconfigure DNS

[Source](https://n1ckbren.mozpi.com/articles/fixed-error-reading-settings-mac-server-app-id-174)